# Install MySQL 5.* and MySQL 8 on a same Linux(Ubuntu) machine?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0

Can we install and run 2 different MySQL versions together on the same Linux(Ubuntu) machine?

Required MySQL versions are

1. MySQL 5.7
2. MySQL 8

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Comment: It is optimal to run one of the versions separately on a virtual machine or docker

Comment: @Daheim I have found the reference https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-unix-servers.html, but while installing 8 it is removing MySQL 5.7

Comment: I guess you just need to run them on different ports and point them to different lib directories,
after that I ask you to share your experience